# Math function not working in angular 4 HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

Using the following line :

```
<div class="card light-blue darken-4" [ngClass]="'card-grad-'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1">
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'floor' of undefined
```

and component.ts.

How to resolve it ?

Even tried using `decare var Math:any` and also tried defining Math in the class but in vain.

Comment: Declare `Math = Math` property in component class. But don't use random in template. `Expression has changed after it was checked` will wait you

Comment: @yurzui that is exactly what is happening. Any way to get it working ?

Answer (score 15):

Declare the Math in your component.ts

**`Math = Math;`**

or create a function that would calculate your value and bind that to ng-class

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
<span>{{Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}}</span>
```

In your ".ts" file :

```
Math: any;
Constructor() {
    this.Math = Math;
}
```

This expression although will lead you to
**Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '6'. Current value: '3'.**

Still you can use Math in your template.

See below link for the expression changed error:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

To get rid of that error you can user "enableProdMode" in app.module.ts.
Like below:

```
import {enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

export class AppModule {}
enableProdMode();
```

Or: use can use "ChangeDetectionStrategy" from angular/core
`import {  Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: '<selector>',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
})`

Comment: Doing what you answered does not solve my problem, although I do not get any errors in the console but the classes that I get in the end are like so:

`<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="card light-blue darken-4 card-grad-31">`


and


`<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="card light-blue darken-4 card-grad-01">`

Which is incorrect given the functionality should produce random numbers between 1 and 10

Comment: Hi Shakti, then it might be some other issue as i am getting random number between 1 to 10 only. here plunk link for the same: https://plnkr.co/edit/MzuxbNytcLcvGRefTrlT?p=preview